# Ableton Live 8.2 won't load second time around

Tags: ableton-live

...it loads up the first time like a charms.
But if I shut it down and try to load it up a second time, I get nothing. Literally nothing. No error, no exception no nothing. I have to reboot to run it again (which is obviously unacceptable)

Any ideas? Suggestions? Something to test?

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this happens with applications that do not shutdown properly. Crack open your list of processes and see if it is running - if so, kill it.

If you can kill the process and reopen succesfully, time to troubleshoot why it is not closing down properly.

Comment: This actually worked, but revealed another problem. If I kill the process, I can then run it one way or the other, but not both. That is, I can open the GUI and run a VM, OR I can run a VM from the command line, but either way, the other will cause an error. This is not acceptable as I have some VMs constantly running, and others I just open for brief periods via the GUI. What the heck caused this? It wasn't always so. I have uninstalled and reinstalled to no avail.